# How to get the data from one browser window to other window in gwt?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, window, jsni

First of all i would like to say that i have gone through all the posts which are similar to my query but i have some different requirement.

In our project we are using gwt to develop the modules, in one of our module, we have "Edit" button which opens a new browser window which includes 'CKEditor'.
We are modifying the data in ckeditor comes(by url) from gwt widget .

The Window opens by using following code snippet(JSNI) in my gwt widget:

```
private static native BodyElement getBodyElement(String url) /*-{    
         var win = window.open("url", "win",      "width=940,height=400,status=1,resizeable=1,scrollbars=1"); // a window object    
         return win.document.body;       
   }-*/;
```

The newly opened window have the html form which is with `ckeditor`.

So here i am closing new window once my form has been submitted but i want the edited text to be displayed in old window.
How can i achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use HTML5, it should be quite easy. Use Messaging.

Take a look here:

[Cross-document messaging](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/web-messaging.html)

With the reference of the newly opened window, yu can establish a communication between both windows.

Comment: not to be a jQuery evangelist, but you can also post-message without HTML5, provided that you have jQuery included. see [this plugin](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-postmessage).

Comment: and i know, [jQuery is not the answer to everything](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif)...